# avoiding duplication while importing into table

Tags: php, mysql, excel

is there a way i can stop a row of data being entered into the database while i'm importing from a csv file, so as to avoid duplication in the database..

NOTE: while the duplictates are not allowed entry othere are entered into to the database.

Here's the importing script i'm working on....

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php require('includes/dbconnect.php'); ?>
<?php require 'includes/header.inc.php'; ?>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT']))
 {
 $fname = $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];//Acquire the name of the file
 $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

  $filename = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];
   $handle = fopen($filename, "r");//Open the file for readability
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {
        $sql = "INSERT into biodata                (student_number, fname, lname,        level) values('$data[0]','$data               [1]','$data[2]','$data[3])";
  mysql_query($sql) or die                          (mysql_error());
     }
     fclose($handle);
     echo "Successfully Imported";
    }
   else
   {
      echo "Invalid File";
   }


   ?>
```

Comment: I'm thinking triggers (or maybe something with the keyword 'DISTINCT').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the student_number column is the primary key, this script won't let you insert rows with the same number and will die as soon as you find one.

If that is indeed the case, you can just change `INSERT INTO table VALUES (...)` to `INSERT INTO table VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE student_number = student_number` to just ignore the error when that happens.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thanks, the answer was spot on.

Comment: Any special reason why my answer was unaccepted after a month?

Comment: bruno that should have being a mistake. I'll fix it now. I'm sorry if it made you uncomfortable, i would have being too if it was me. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO table VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEYUPDATE student_number = 
student_number